# API - easy to use vs. easy to understand

Tags: polymorphism, naming-conventions, api-design

I have some questions regarding readability vs. usability in a web application and I couldn't find the answers I was looking for. I will explain my questions using an example.

My web application needs to display some information about houses, cars and animals. I have an API endpoint which returns all items resulting in something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "car"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "house"
  },
  ...
]
```

So far so good, but now I need more information about all items. This information is stored and gotten from the API as a reference (an ID string referring to the info). Houses and cars can only contain 1 reference and animals can contain 1 or more references.

How the service is set up is not relevant, but the API is now returning the references like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "car",
    "references": ["car1"]
  },
  ...
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "animals",
    "references": ["animal1", "animal3"]
  },
  ...
]
```

*Note that also the car item is returning an array of references, but it can only contain 1 reference!*

This setup makes my JavaScript front-end really easy, it just loops over all items and (if needed) performs another API call for each reference.

**Question 1**
I am now trying to figure out if this is the right way to go as the API incorrectly suggests that a car and a house can have multiple references. I do have API documentation which can clearly explain that they can not, but I also like an API that does not need a lot of documentation as it is pretty self-explanatory.

**Question 2**
My back-end (written in Java) has an abstract `Item` model which contains the `id` and `type` members. The `id` property is just a random string and the `type` member is either `house`, `car` or `animals`. Then there are resp. 3 subclasses called `House`, `Car` and `Animal` each of which restricts the `type` member to it's own type. What would be the best way of implementing the references in these models?

I could add a `references` member on the `Item` model which is an array. This would make it really easy to display in the front-end. But if the API is going to change as suggested in question 1, it would make more sense to:

- give the `Car` model a `car` member that has a single `Car` reference
- give the `House` model a `house` member that has a single `House` reference
- give the `Animal` model a `animals` member that is an array of `Animal` references

Resulting in something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "car",
    "car": "car1"
  },
  ...
  {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "animals",
    "animals": ["animal1", "animal3"]
  },
  ...
]
```

But this would give me some issues in the front-end trying to figure out what kind of models it got, displaying it, etc.

Hope I explained it right and if anyone can point me in the right direction!

**EDIT** I need all the `Item`'s and the order they are returned in also matters.

Comment: Strong typing is a job for XML (and an XML schema), not JSON.

Comment: @VGR True, but XML would make it even harder to use. Besides, the question is not so much about typing my response but how I can solve this so that is easy to use and still clear what each property may contain.
@ anyone who -1'd my question, explain please? Is my question unclear or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting one possibility : You dont have to expose the same model as you use internaly.
The more important things about a data model is the business behind it. So Ask yourself, does it make sens for an Item to have references ?
If yes, then add a List in references, else add a unique reference in car and a List in Animals.
As for the JSON part, it greatly depend of the endpoint you are requesting. You should have a specific model by endpoint. If you request /items, then all the element of the json array should have the same model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The point is, this is a matter of polymorphism. I am doing a `.../items` request and either way I am getting `Item` models, but the `Item` model is abstract and can thus be a `House` or an `Animal`.

Comment: That does not actualy matter here. If you have one endpoint, you should use one model. If you want to handle multiple models, then create multiple endpoints.

Comment: This would make it hard to maintain right? I mean, adding extra `Item` implementations (e.g. a `Computer` model) would require me to add extra endpoints.

Comment: It would make it a lit bit harder to maintain but a lot clearer and therefore simpler to use.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the help so far, but I now see that I failed to mention that I need all items to be displayed and that the order they are returned in matters. This makes this option not viable in my case. I'll edit my question!